# How to get jQuery/JavaScript working on the website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use this code: http://codepen.io/chrisgrabinski/pen/JhnBl but for some reason the .js file does not want to load up properly.

This is what I have so far in my HTML head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/landing.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/landing.js"></script>
```

And this is what my landing.js file looks like:

```
function toggleScroll() {
  $('.start-login, .start-signup').toggleClass('active');
  //$('html, body, .section-start').animate({
  //  scrollTop: 0
  //}, 200);
}

$('.btn-signup, .btn-back-login').click(function() {
  toggleScroll();
});

$('.btn-signup, .btn-back-login').on('touchstart', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  toggleScroll();
});
```

You can find the rest of the code in the previously mentioned link.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure its not loading properly? Everything looks correct

Comment: is event handling code wrapped in `document.ready`. Have you checked console to see if file is loading?